# Suggestion: tag aliases on CV

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs

A question about an algorithm is conventionally tagged with 'Algorithm', but the academic field of study is generally known as 'Algorithms'.

It would be nice if I could write 'Algorithms' on my CV and have that be a pointer to my questions and answers for the tag 'Algorithm'.

(I don't know whether there are only a few cases like this and some kind of global mapping would cover 99% of everybody, or whether there should be a way to write arbitrary name/tag pairs on individual CVs. Thoughts?)

Answer (score 1):

The tags are going to be necessarily a bit loose. Despite whichever is more "accurate" I would recommend going with whichever form is popular on SO as it reflects what can survive, tagging-wise, in the wild.

Comment: Why 'necessarily a bit loose'?  Why couldn't I write, say, [algorithms:algorithm] and get a CV that plays in both worlds?  It would be just like link aliasing in a wiki.

People might also prefer to get away from the SO tag syntax altogether by writing [Visual Studio:visual-studio] for example.  That would be useful even if the tags never do turn into live links.

Counterargument:  I guess this makes most sense when thinking about employers who are not searching via SO itself.  If an employer *knows* to search for 'algorithm' then they might be confused to get a resume with 'Algorithms'.